# Facebook Privacy Policies

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

Does anyone know if I save public_profile data in my database when a user accesses my app with your Facebook account I will be violating the FaceBook privacy policies?

Comment: If its "Public Data" why would this be a violation?

Comment: Public Data means that anyone can see it if they go to Facebook.com. Doesn't mean anyone can download it and do what ever they feel like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is mentioned against it in the data privacy policy. Check it out:

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#data

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up on the [Privacy Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) facebook has

Depending on how you are storing this information and as long as you are not breaking any laws you should be fine.
Make sure you don't breach IP and privacy laws as well as FB EULA and CFAA